# plotting list of points and connecting

Tags: python

I have a given list with (x, y) coordinates ranging from 0-15,000 like so:

```
[(3956.1443, 7572.584), (4234.46, 8415.766), (3751.9963, 7667.078), (4160.75, 9336.5), (6065.931, 10525.833), (4775.282, 8665.462), (1890.2118, 8448.749), (4201.731, 7603.609), (6445.223, 9336.452)]
```

What is the easiest way to plot these values on a grid and connect them with a line such that:

```
(3956.1443, 7572.584) -> (4234.46, 8415.766) -> (3751.9963, 7667.078) -> etc
```

Each point is connected to the point following it. The list is much longer then what I shared.

Comment: What's the specific problem you meet?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA I scraped resource locations in a game from a website, determined optimal route for visitation, and then want to plot the points and overlay it back onto the game map.

Comment: There are many module about Visualization, have you tried them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try splitting the tuples into separate lists and plot using matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

coord = [(3956.1443, 7572.584), (4234.46, 8415.766), (3751.9963, 7667.078), (4160.75, 9336.5), (6065.931, 10525.833),
     (4775.282, 8665.462), (1890.2118, 8448.749), (4201.731, 7603.609), (6445.223, 9336.452)]

x = []
y = []
for t in coord:
    x.append(t[0])
    y.append(t[1])

plt.plot(x, y, '-o')
plt.show()
```